# clarification of decltype output when multiplying 2 const ints

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, decltype

```
int main()
{
 const int a = 1;
 const int b = 2;
 typedef decltype(a*b) multiply_type;
 cout << typeid(multiply_type).name() << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

The return value of the program is that multiply_type is int. I'm quite surprised. I expected the type deduction to yield const int and since the expression yields a pr value, the resultant type would be const int.

PS: With auto the return value would be int as it drops the const qualifier.

Any ideas why multiply_type is int instead of const int with decltype ?

Edit: Added an addition example which is also related to cv-qualifier.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>


using namespace std;

struct Details
{
    int m_age;
};

int main()
{
 const Details* detail = new Details();
 typedef decltype((detail->m_age)) age_type;
 cout << typeid(age_type).name() << endl;

 int a = 1;
 age_type age = a;
 age = 10; // This is not possible. Read only. 
 cout << typeid(age).name() << endl; // This returns the type as int though. Then why is 20 not possble ?
 return 0;

}
```

Edit 2: Check our the link. 
http://thbecker.net/articles/auto_and_decltype/section_07.html
`

```
int x;
const int& crx = x;
/ The type of (cx) is const int. Since (cx) is an lvalue,
// decltype adds a reference to that: cx_with_parens_type
// is const int&.
typedef decltype((cx)) cx_with_parens_type;`
```

Comment: Value categories and cv-qualifiers are independent things. In your particular case, [expr]/6 applies; there are no prvalues of `const` scalar type.

Comment: See my edit. I meant to say, the expression is a pr-value.

Comment: I have no idea how that's related to my answer.

Comment: Why do you think that `a * b` should return a const value?

Comment: Why do u think it shouldn't.

Comment: @Columbo Check out my latest edits.

Comment: @KodeWarrior Because I have never encountered a language rule that says that constness of return value of an operation depends on constness of the arguments (at least for in-built arithmetic operators. You can achieve it for custom types with overloading, though). And because it would achieve nothing useful.

Comment: Btw., `age_type` is `const int&`, not `int`. The string produced by `typeid` is not really expressive.

Comment: Yup. I know age_type is const int&. But don't know why typeid says as int. Weird and confused the hell out of me.

Comment: @user2079303 That's fine. So, are u saying that x * y where x, y = const int is always int ? Could you please explain about this more ? May be I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: @KodeWarrior I'm saying that I would expect it to be. As I said, I know of no language rule that says otherwise, and it would make very little difference to anything. The return value is not an lvalue, so whether it is const or not, you cannot assign to it anyway.

Comment: okay I kind of seem to get it.

Comment: In [November 2014 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) section 3.10 "Lvalues and rvalues": "Note: class and array prvalues can have cv-qualified
types; other prvalues always have cv-unqualified types.".

Comment: The special case of parentheses with decltype is covered in section 7.1.6.2 item (?) 4.

Answer (score 1):

`decltype` evaluate it argument as it is, `decltype(i)` where `i` is *cv-qualified* lvalue, results in declaring type cv-qualified, but the expression of `i*i` in `decltype(i*i)` create a non materialized prvalue with type of `i` with non *cv-qualified*, prvalue don't have an explicit notion of constness. your code produce the same as:

```
using T = const int;
static_assert(is_same<int, decltype(0)>(), "Failed");
```

The fact that `typeid` is not showing the cv-qualification is because they a ignored:

> [5.2.8.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid) - If the type of the expression or type-id is a cv-qualified type, the result of the typeid expression refers to a std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified type.